# Laravel passport - middleware client_credentials bearer token not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, clientcredential

I have a laravel project, use Passport Client Credentials to get Bearer Tokens,
I create client id and secret id using

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

And get

[image: client id & secret id]

and get bearer/access code from postman like this
[image: bearer code]

but after call other api like this using this barear but not working

```
Route::middleware('client_credentials')->post('/test',[ApiController::class, 'va_bills']);
```

and the output just

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

But if I change the route to be a closure function its work like this

```
Route::middleware('client_credentials')->post('/test', function (Request $request) {
    echo 'nice';
});
```

[image: output closure function]

I have add this to kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
..
'client_credentials'     => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class,
..
```

and change the driver

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',//instead of token 
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

I have also add this to .htaccess,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)

RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

but for your info I dont have .htaccess before and I run my app using `php artisan serve`
I have read many solution but still not work,

can some one help me to out from this problem? Thank you for your time.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?